# Question on the Definition of Automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I am missing something very basic here, but here it goes. As a consequence of the definition of a homomorphism we must have that $f(e) = e'$. Consider $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^*$ and the map $x \to 2x$. It is a bijection but does not satisfies the multiplicative property but how can we claim it is an automorphism since $f(1) = 2 \neq 1$.

Edit: Does not satisfy multiplicative property.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}/5$ or $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_5$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Comment: What is $(\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z_5)^*$?

Comment: As a side note, you should use $\to$ for the arrow that goes between the domain and codomain of a function, and $\mapsto$ when describing a mapping itself. Here, the map should be written $x \mapsto 2x$ (which is a function $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^* \to (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^*$).

Comment: Thanks I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that this is not a homomorphism! Indeed, it is not multiplicative: if $f(x) = 2x$ then $f(xy) = 2xy$ but $f(x)f(y) = (2x)(2y) = 4xy$. Then pick $x = y = 1$ to see that $f(xy) \neq f(x)f(y)$.

Like you said, any multiplicative function on this set (a.k.a. any endomorpism of $\mathbb{Z}_5^*$) will automatically send $1$ to $1$. Math is not broken!

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for some reason I was really confused.

Comment: It happens to everyone :)

Comment: If you don't mind could you elaborate on this point of the video. Starts at 10:38. Conext before it might help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUh7JBbKqVw&list=PL8yHsr3EFj51pjBvvCPipgAT3SYpIiIsJ&index=3

Comment: @JamesEade Ah, it seems I've misunderstood the context you gave. In this video, $(\mathbb{Z}/5)^*$ is defined to be the group of group automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/5$, and the map $x \mapsto 2x$ is going from $\mathbb{Z}/5$ to itself, with the claim that $x \mapsto 2x$ is an *element* of $(\mathbb{Z}/5)^*$! This *is* a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/5$ to $\mathbb{Z}/5$, because the group operation of $\mathbb{Z}/5$ is addition modulo $5$, and $2(x+y) = 2x + 2y$. Note that the identity element of $\mathbb{Z}/5$ is $0$, and indeed $2\cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: Another note: we can talk about groups using either additive or multiplicative notation. It's common to use additive notation for abelian groups and multiplicative notation for non-abelian groups, but this is not a hard-and-fast rule; for example, we usually prefer to use multiplicative notation to discuss the group $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^*$ even though it is always abelian (try to prove this!). If we instead used additive notation to discuss the group $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^*$, then the map $x \mapsto 2x : (\mathbb{Z}/n)^* \to (\mathbb{Z}/n)^*$ is a homomorphism, because (1/2)

Comment: ... in additive notation, $2x$ no longer means "the group operation applied to the elements $2$ and $x$"; instead it means $x + x$, i.e. "the group operation applied to the elements $x$ and $x$". You can check that this is a homomorphism because $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^*$ is abelian. (2/2)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! So $Aut(Z/5) = (Z/5Z)^*$.

Comment: Oh yes, it seems that the lines video first defines (around 7:15) $(\mathbb{Z}/5)^*$ to be the set of nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}/5$ under multiplication (this is a bad definition because $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^*$ cannot always be defined this way) then later (around 10:30) explains that this group can be identified with both the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/5$ *and* the group $\mathbb{Z}/4$. This is true, but it's good to know that in general (by one definition) $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^*=\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/n)$. (1/2)

Comment: $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^*=\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/n)$ can always be identified with the set of multiplicatively invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ under multiplication, but this is not always the same as the set of nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ under multiplication (indeed the nonzero elements form a group iff every nonzero element is multiplicatively invertible iff $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^* \cong \mathbb{Z}/(n-1)$ iff $n$ is prime). (2/2)